# JsonMappingException when calling getItem using Podio Java API

Tags: podio

I am attempting to perform a `getItem` using the *Podio Java API*:

```
itemAPI.getItem(485941464);
```

results in:

```
Error: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No enum constant com.podio.app.ApplicationFieldType.TAG (through reference chain: com.podio.item.Item["fields"]->com.podio.item.FieldValuesView["type"])
```

This is with (supposedly) the latest Java API.

Unless I am missing something, it would appear that the `com.podio.app.ApplicationFieldType.TAG` enum is not in the latest Java API.

Can you let me know if this is an accurate assessment or if I am missing something that you can think of?

Comment: can you please share full stack-trace of exception?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having an issue with a specific client, you might consider opening a GitHub issue against it. If you are interested enough you might consider submitting a pull request to correct the issue. The Java client appears to have been inactive for a while now, so there is no guarantee that it will be actively updated any time soon

Alternatively, you could consider bypassing the Java client and directly [interacting with the Podio API directly](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-22360).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today (error: com.podio.app.ApplicationFieldType.PHONE in my case) and I concur with your assessment. I have an item without a phone number and it can get the fields fine (I use getItems() in this instance rather than getItem()) however I try and get an Item with a phone number stored rather than just an empty field and it crashes. Seems like the podio API can't read in certain types (so far Phone and Tag).

Best suggestion I can make is to avoid having those types on the Items you want to read. I'll be saving Phone numbers as pure numbers. If that's not an option you'll either have to dive into the source code yourself or wait for an update to the API.

Comment: Just investigated further on my Item and also Email generates the same error so the list of types is now Tag, Phone and Email.